# Json_decode not working in Flickr API

Tags: php, json, flickr

I have this code

```
$feed_Flickr = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=44545397@N03&lang=en-us&format=json';
    $Flickr = file_get_contents($feed_Flickr);
    $Flickr = str_replace('jsonFlickrFeed(','',$Flickr);
    $Flickr = str_replace('})','}',$Flickr);
    $flickrvalue = json_decode($Flickr);
    print_r($flickrvalue);
```

print_r return nothing what's the wrong with code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data isn't valid JSON and that's why [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) isn't working. You can try validating it with a website such as [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com).

From the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) documentation:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

That explains why you're not getting any outputs.

**UPDATE:**

It turns out Flickr escapes single quotes (`'`) and apparently this isn't allowed and makes the JSON invalid. You can use `str_replace()` to get around this:

```
$flickrResponse = str_replace("\\'", "'", $Flickr);
```

Also, as the [Flickr API documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) says, instead of using the normal JSON, you can get the raw JSON by appending the `nojsoncallback` parameter with the value of `1` to the URL, like so:

> `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=44545397@N03&lang=en-us&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`

So, with that changes, our code should be working:

```
$feed_Flickr = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=44545397@N03&lang=en-us&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';
$Flickr = file_get_contents($feed_Flickr);
$flickrResponse = str_replace("\\'", "'", $Flickr);
$results = json_decode($flickrResponse, true);
print_r($results);
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6ZKK3f)

Comment: that's mean Flickr API has data isn't valid JSON?

Comment: @magedali: yes, this appears to be a bug. See http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157622950514923/

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the variable!

**Flickrn!**

```
 $Flickr = str_replace('})','}',$Flickrn);
```